# Control doesn't go into the if condition in the onActivityResult method when using the DropboxSyncAPI Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have followed the basic steps on the site's tutorial for the [android DropboxSyncAPI](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android) but, I can't seem to link my account, it keeps failing. I have put a TextView on the screen which I change when it enters certain parts of the code.

What happens when I run the app: It asks me to log in to a dropbox account when it open, and when I "allow" the application permission, it goes back into the application and the text displayed on the TextView is: "I did not approve this"

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager;
import com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxFileSystem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;
    private String APP_KEY="key";
    private String APP_SECRET="secret";

    TextView checking;

    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checking= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checking);
        mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        startLink();

    }

    private void startLink() {
        mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.v("Activity Result","entered onActivityResult: resultCode: "+resultCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            checking.setText("Request link to dbx");
            Log.v("Activity Result","Entered the request link to DBX if condition: resultCode: "+resultCode);


            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.v("Activity Result","Connection succesful: resultCode: "+resultCode);

                checking.setText("Connected");
                try {
                    DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Activity Result", "unable to get associated DbxFileSystem: resultCode: "+resultCode);
                }
                // ... Start using Dropbox files.
            } else {
                Log.v("Activity Result","Link failed or was cancelled by the user: resultCode: "+resultCode);
                checking.setText("I did not approve this");
                // ... Link failed or was cancelled by the user.
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


}
```

and this is my log:

```
03-21 00:03:44.219  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
03-21 00:03:44.219  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11387: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11393: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9077: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 391: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 413: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-21 00:03:44.229  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.dropbox.ledger.android.Ledger.newBuilder, referenced from method com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initLedger
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 12052: Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;.newBuilder ()Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger$Builder;
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
03-21 00:03:44.269  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.279  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/LedgerUrlCallbackImpl; interface 1486 'Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/LedgerUrlCallback;'
03-21 00:03:44.279  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/LedgerUrlCallbackImpl;' failed
03-21 00:03:44.279  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x34d6 at 0x90 in Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/CoreAccountManager;.initLedger
03-21 00:03:44.279  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager﹕ Prepared cache dir '/data/data/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi/app_DropboxSyncCache/zu8comzdp8dkq8v'.
03-21 00:03:44.279  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi-2/libDropboxSync.so 0x41bbcaa0
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi-2/libDropboxSync.so 0x41bbcaa0
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.dropbox.ledger.android.Ledger.getHandles, referenced from method com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeEnv$Config.<init>
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12050: Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;.getHandles ()Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger$NativeLedgerHandles;
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0168
03-21 00:03:44.289  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x14db at 0x16c in Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeEnv$Config;.<init>
03-21 00:03:44.299  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x14da at 0x170 in Lcom/dropbox/sync/android/NativeEnv$Config;.<init>
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccount﹕ Dropbox user 390717823 linked.
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;)
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.dropbox.ledger.android.Ledger.log, referenced from method com.dropbox.sync.android.AnalyticsEvent.log
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12051: Lcom/dropbox/ledger/android/Ledger;.log (Ljava/lang/String;)V
03-21 00:03:44.309  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0078
03-21 00:03:44.319  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager﹕ Dropbox initialized for application: zu8comzdp8dkq8v (com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi/1.0 DropboxSync/3.1.2 (Android; 4.3; PANASONIC Panasonic ELUGA A armeabi-v7a; en_US))
03-21 00:03:44.319  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager﹕ Requesting link for a Dropbox new account.
03-21 00:03:44.339  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService﹕ DbxSyncService starting.
03-21 00:03:44.439  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
03-21 00:03:44.449  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-21 00:03:44.449  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-21 00:03:44.449  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.2.1.5.04.03.00.191.009_msm8610_LNX.LA.3.2.1.5__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.05
    Build Date: 06/10/14 Tue
    Local Branch: mybranch3525181
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.2.1.5
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.2.1.5.04.03.00.191.009 +  NOTHING
03-21 00:03:44.499  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-21 00:03:44.979  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor﹕ Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/108.160.165.142,port=443,localPort=41111]
03-21 00:03:46.209  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService﹕ DbxSyncService stopping.
03-21 00:03:50.839  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1341K, 17% free 6882K/8264K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
03-21 00:03:50.839  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccount﹕ Dropbox user 390717823 linked.
03-21 00:03:50.849  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager﹕ Duplicate link for user ID 390717823, unlinking new account.
03-21 00:03:50.849  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccount﹕ User 390717823 unlinked.
03-21 00:03:50.879  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService﹕ DbxSyncService starting.
03-21 00:03:50.889  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi V/Activity Result﹕ entered onActivityResult: resultCode: 0
03-21 00:03:50.889  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi V/Activity Result﹕ Entered the request link to DBX if condition: resultCode: 0
03-21 00:03:50.889  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi V/Activity Result﹕ Link failed or was cancelled by the user: resultCode: 0
03-21 00:03:51.199  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor﹕ Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/108.160.165.142,port=443,localPort=41112]
03-21 00:03:52.229  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreBackgroundProcessor﹕ Notifying server of unlink for uid='390717823' token='{oauth2:"nuxHnUEt_tAAAAAAAAAALLsxsnMV86gWSip0JF1YfE6egOZynnEkhpirXU9tx4Y9"}'.
03-21 00:03:52.479  18691-18708/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreStandardHttpRequestor﹕ Created new socket: SSL socket over Socket[address=api.dropbox.com/108.160.165.142,port=443,localPort=41113]

03-21 00:03:53.559  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi I/com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService﹕ DbxSyncService stopping.
```

Update: 
I have put more logs in the onActivityResult method.
Also, this started happening when I ran the application for the second time, before which the application was running fine: The TextView even displayed "connection successful"!

Comment: I'm a little confused. The title of your question says "Control doesn't go into the onActivityResult method," but the message you report seeing ("I did not approve this") is only set in `onActivityResult`, right? So it seems like control is definitely going into `onActivityResult`, but for some reason the `resultCode` isn't `Activity.RESULT_OK`. Is that correct?

Comment: @smarx I'm sorry, that's what I meant! I'll edit the question right away.

Comment: Can you add some logging in each code path and post the new output so we can see exactly what is getting executed when, how many times, etc.? E.g., adding logging to each part of `onActivityResult`. Logging out the value of `resultCode` too would probably also be good.

Comment: Hello again @Greg I have added the logs. I think this is happening because the application has already authorised once online: which might be the reason for the log: `03-21 00:03:50.849  18691-18691/com.ashwinpraveen.driveapp.dropboxsyncapi W/com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager﹕ Duplicate link for user ID 390717823, unlinking new account.` I do not know how to resolve it, even if it were the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify what's going on. It looks like the issue is just that you're linking the same account again, so you get the `RESULT_OK` code, since nothing really changed. If you just wanted to continue using that same account, there's no reason to call `startLink` again. (If you linked a different account, you would get `RESULT_OK`.)

Comment: @Greg Could you please tell me what I'm to do if I want to check weather the account is linked? Also, Is there a way I can do the authentication process without leaving the application(without opening the mobile browser application)? Maybe using a webView? or using the dropbox application?

Comment: The methods `hasLinkedAccount`, `getLinkedAccount`, `getLinkedAccounts` are useful for this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount

Comment: There isn't currently a way to control the authorization flow using the official SDK like that. If the official Dropbox app is installed, that will be used by default. Otherwise, the browser will be used. We're tracking this as a feature request though.